# Why is this code thought to violate Law of Demeter?

Tags: oop, law-of-demeter

Here's a method from my Android app:

```
public ViewHolderBase buildView(PlayerResult playerResult)
{
    View result = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.player_result,
        null);
    this.helper = new ViewHelper(result);

    ViewHolderBase holder = createViewHolder();

    TextView playerName = helper.findTextView(R.id.playerName);
    holder.setPlayerNameTextView(playerName); // <-- alleged violation

    TableLayout tableLayout = helper.findTableLayout(R.id.tlPossibleResults);
    populateTableLayout(holder, tableLayout, playerResult);
    holder.setView(result); // <-- another one
    return holder;
}
```

Android Studio "thinks" that these two lines violate the Law of Demeter:

```
holder.setPlayerNameTextView(playerName);
holder.setView(result);
```

I don't get it. Here's the [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> The Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method m of an object
>   O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of objects:
>
> - O itself
> - m's parameters
> - Any objects created/instantiated within m
> - O's direct component objects
> - A global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of m

So? `holder` variable **is** created / instantiated within `m`.

Fair enough, it's instantiation is delegated to `createViewHolder` method... Should it make a difference? (side question).

It doesn't for the IDE - if I instantiate `holder` directly instead, warnings are still shown.

**Question:**

Is Android Studio wrong? Or is my understanding of Law of Demeter lacking? If the latter is true, how should I refactor this bit to satisfy LoD?

Comment: As far as I can see there's nothing wrong in these two lines.

Comment: Can you show pls the createViewHolder method or tell the implementing class of createViewHolder.

Comment: @Diversity - `createViewHolder` is abstract in this class (I use abstract method pattern). It's overriden in derived class and the implementation is a one-liner: `return new RangeViewHolder();`. But as I said, even if I replace the `createViewHolder` with a direct, inlined instantiation (`= new RangeViewHolder()`), the warnings persist

Answer (score 1):

Neither object is actually instantiated in the "m"; both holder and result are the return value of a function, so technically an object which has been created elsewhere.

Of course you know that "createViewHolder" simply creates an object for someone else's use, and I assume the same is true for "inflater.inflate"; so you can probably disregard those as false positives.
But there's no way to programmatically tell an analyst software that, so I'd assume that's why you get the warnings.

One point: since you're delegating the createViewHolder to a child class, you open yourself the code up; thus, I'd still call it a violation of the Law of Demeter. Doesn't mean your code is bad, in my opinion.